# Why always the first number is dialled..!

Tags: android

I am writing code for searching a contact and making the call. My code can list the contact names and select particular contact. But when i dial to that selected contact, it speaks out the selected name but dials to the first name in the contact list.Can anyone help me how to write the code for calling particular number by selecting the name from the list of contacts.
Thanks in advance.

here is the code that i use to search particular contact number. but selects the first number.

```
 private void populateContacts()
 { 

   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 

   Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,  null, null, null); 

   if (cur.getCount() > 0) { 

   while (cur.moveToNext())
   { 

       // ID AND NAME FROM CONTACTS CONTRACTS 
        id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 

        // GET PHONE NUMBERS WITH QUERY STRING 
      if (Integer.parseInt(cur .getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) { 

        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID 
                       + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null); 

         // WHILE WE HAVE CURSOR GET THE PHONE NUMERS 
        while (pCur.moveToNext())
         { 

              name = cur .getString(cur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));    

             Log.i("jni", "ID :" + id); 
             Log.i("jni", "NAME :" + name); 

                 // Do something with phones 
                 //int phoneColumn = pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA);
                 //      number =pCur.getString(phoneColumn);

            phone = pCur.getString(pCur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA)); 

           Contacts.add( name+ phone  );
         }

  } 
    //      pCur.close(); 

 }
```

Comment: You need to provide us with some code.

Comment: ya as told by Richard Schneider this is not enough to analyze the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should specify more info in order we can help you. but

You should use the People Content Provider **android.provider.Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI** .
Check this info http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html and you will be able to know how to do it ;)

There is an explanation about Content providers using the Contacts Content Provider, you will see there how they filter a specific contact and get their info